# Picasso failed to load image from url written in bangla

Tags: android, image, url, imageview, picasso

I used Picasso library to load image from remote server. Image url is written in mix language(bangla/english). In some device it loads perfectly as well as Chrome browser. But in my Huawei device(model TIT-AL00))) it failed to load. Default image shown. My code is:

```
String subjectIconUrl = https://devallorshathistorage.blob.core.windows.net/subject/Image_Subject_2018-06-12-064043044_কৃষিশিক্ষা_Krishi Shikkha.png;

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(subjectIconUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_default)
            // To fit image into imageView
            .fit()
            // To prevent fade animation
            .noFade()
            .into(holder.imageSubjectIcon);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the url

```
Uri.encode(url,"UTF-8");
```

and try to load

example

```
String subjectIconUrl = https://xyz/subject/Image_Subject_2018-06-12-064043044_কৃষিশিক্ষা_Krishi Shikkha.png;
String encoded_url = Uri.encode(subjectIconUrl); 

Picasso.with(context)
            .load(encoded_url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_default)
            // To fit image into imageView
            .fit()
            // To prevent fade animation
            .noFade()
            .into(holder.imageSubjectIcon);
```

refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#encode(java.lang.String)

Comment: after encoding all of my images (including file name written in english that is load before) does not load.